# Change a tag font size in relation to it's current font size

Tags: html, css

Not sure if this is actually possible to do. Is it possible to increase/decrease a specific HTML tag (h1,p,...) based on their current size; Only using CSS and HTML? **I know the JavaScript way.**

The percentage of smaller/larger will be determined by the user. it might be for instance 97%. Then it should be 97% of the font-size of the element.

Example:

CSS:

`h1 { font-size: 2rem }`

HTML:

`<h1 style="font-size: (20% larger)"></h1>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, [CSS `var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var()) and calc() could help

```css
h1 {
  --font-size: 2rem;/* set a var for your font-size. --font-size is a valid name for a CSS var() */

/* use that var() */

font-size: var(--font-size);
}
```

```html
<h1 style="font-size: calc( var(--font-size) *  1.2 )">Enlarge 20%</h1>
<h1 style="font-size: 2.64rem">2.2rem x 1.2 = 2.64rem </h1>
<h1 style="font-size: var(--font-size);">2rem</h1>
<h1 style="font-size:2rem;">2rem</h1>
<h1>from the sheet</h1>
```

Comment: Do I need both --font-size and font-size in h1 like your answer? `h1{--font-size: 2rem; font-size: var(--font-size);}`

Comment: You need both , so where you do not want to resize your font, it is 2rem, else it will be the default font-size used by your browser (or reset style sheet if you load one prior your own style).  @EvikGhazarian